# How to reinstall Maven libraries?

Tags: java, maven, node-modules

Coming from `npm/yarn` background, for each and every project we will have `node_modules` which holds all the dependencies and libraries, if we wish to reset our project from clean state, we can always delete the entire `node_modules` and reinstall the libraries.

```
rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && yarn install
```

Now trying to learn Java and trying out `Maven`, correct me if I'm wrong, we define the dependencies on `pom.xml`, which essentially the same as `package.json` on `yarn/npm`, and the downloaded dependencies will be stored on `/target`?

Is `/target` equals to `node_modules` and hence I can actually delete entire `/target` and restart the downloading process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force re-download of release dependency using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959499/force-re-download-of-release-dependency-using-maven)

Comment: You shouldn't normally need to do this, maven dependencies are versioned, and except for snapshots they will be stable and cannot change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dependencies are not stored in `target`, but in `.m2/repository` in your user directory. This is the so-called *local repository*. It also holds all artifacts build on that computer/account.

You can delete it if necessary and only lose your local builds.

The `target` directory, on the other hand, gathers the (intermediate and final) results of a build. It can also be deleted, usually by using `mvn clean`.

Comment: But `m2` is in user directory, which means if my machine have 5 individual projects, all 5 projects' dependencies will be sharing this `m2` directory?

Comment: Yes. It is a kind of cache, so you can share it as long as you do not run builds of different projects in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the .m2 folder lying in the below location somewhat
and then do update maven project.You can also do (Force update of snapshots/releases").See this answer -[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196247/force-update-of-snapshots-releases-what-does-it-mean)

Edit-As JF suggested ,the folder also contains the `settings.xml` ,A  file that contains global settings for all maven executions,which you might not want to delete ,so you can just remove the repository folder,and reinstall your dependencies.

```
Unix/Mac OS X – ~/.m2/repository
Windows – C:\Users\{your-username}\.m2\repository
```

Comment: Be careful: The `.m2` folder can also contain the `settings.xml` which you do not want to delete.

Comment: You can also use `mvn dependency:purge-local-Repository` https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html

Answer (score 2):

you can re-install the maven dependencies using the following command:

mvn dependency:purge-local-repository

Answer (score 1):

there is no node_modles equivalent for maven, there is a central local repository maintained .m2/repository folder in per system.

Maven first search for the dependency in that local repo if not found then goes to maven central.

So if you want to delete your local cashed repository you can just simply delete all the folders in .m2/repository folder.

Then maven will not found the dependencies locally and will go for outside which is maven central.

And target contains the build artifact for each project. And
 mvn clean install 
command will  execute the two lifecycle phases clean and install. To run install, maven will run all the phases preceding install in the default maven lifecycle.

For further reference .

[build life cycle](http://%20https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basic)

Comment: If I have 5 projects, all sharing the same `m2` repo, deleting folders in `m2` means I will be forced to perform re-download for each and every other 4 projects?

Comment: For example if you use dependency com.example.something version:0.0.1 then no matter how many projects uses that exact version will get that from m2 . All of your projects will use that version from your m2 local repo.

Comment: Nö only the first build which needs a file will re-download it @isaac

Answer (score 0):

I'm still fairly new with Maven but I believe this will explain what your asking.

1. When you set up your local repository for files/packages that are downloaded based on your POM dependencies they will be stored there and not in your 'target' folder.
2. The target folder is used to house all of your java files as well as the dependency files you specified in your pom but these are copies from your 'repository' folder that is setup on your local box.
3. When you run clean on your machine it will remove all the files in the 'target' folder. Your originally downloaded dependencies will remain in the 'repository' directory that you setup.